# Wearing running shoes for casual walk

Tags: running-shoes, shoes

I like to walk a lot and ususally I am walking quite fast covering large distances on foot.

What if I buy a couple of running shoes (particullary I like those: [Fresh Foam Boracay v3](http://www.newbalance.com/pd/fresh-foam-boracay-v3/MBORA-V3.html#color=Thunder_with_Alpha%20Orange)) for everyday walk. Will it be healthy for my foot wearing it for non-sport activities / causually?

Comment: I personally wear my "worn down trail running shoes" for not-to-challenging-hikes in the woods/hills. So far no health/muscle/pain complaints here.

Comment: It's pretty much accepted in the scientific community that there is almost no difference between most running shoes. Whether it's air pumps, gel shock absorbers, rounded heels, "space age materials", or even the various "minimalist" shoes, your feet compensate. You just want sites that aren't going around on your feet, but aren't so tight that they're cutting off circulation.